# What is the purpose of adding an asterisk (*) at start and end of word?

Tags: punctuation

What is the purpose of enclosing words in asterisks a.k.a. stars (*)? For example:

> The other that *must* be kept correct.

Comment: In what context have you seen this? The usual effect is to emphasise the word but if it is in mini-markdown (like Stack Exchange) single asterisks are used to add italics.

Comment: Encountered in various articles. Could you post an answer?

Comment: @BulatM. Could you edit your original question to include quotes (with references) to the articles you are referring to ?

Comment: I would generally be done for emphasis.

Comment: Sorry, lost that quote, anyway, thanks, problem solved.

Comment: I'm reminded of: "Mary on the ice did frisk. How foolish of her her *!" Possibly I have violated a rule of ELU, but you have to admit this is an easy way to remember the name of *, as well as that name's  pronunciation.(It is strange but true that people are likely to treat the s in "isk" as a silent s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a form of emphasis that is probably used due to typographical emphasis like boldface or italics not being available and all-caps being too obnoxious. This is common in these situations and also the way to denote italics in [markdown](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).